# libgcc-s1 breaks gcc-9 on Ubuntu 18.04 arm64

Tags: 18.04, arm64

Somehow both gcc-7 and gcc-9 were removed from my Ubuntu 18.04.4 arm64 system and we need these to compile our code. To me, it seems like an update to libgcc-s1 as of 04-05-2020 has broken the arm64 compatibility for these in 18.04. Does anyone have a solution or workaround?

When I try to reinstall them I get:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-9 g++-9 gcc-7 g++-7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++-7 : Depends: libstdc++-7-dev (= 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
 g++-9 : Depends: libstdc++-9-dev (= 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-7 : Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-9 : Depends: libgcc-9-dev (= 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

if I try to install these dependencies I get:

```bsh
$ sudo apt install libstdc++-9-dev libgcc-9-dev libstdc++-7-dev libgcc-7-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc-s1 : Breaks: libgcc-7-dev (< 7.5.0-4) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
             Breaks: libgcc-9-dev (< 9.2.1-26) but 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have checked that there are no held packages and found no available updates for libgcc-s1. I am using the repo `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` and my libgcc-s1 is version 10-20200405-0ubuntu1~18.04.

Update 07/08: We updated our code to be compatible to gcc10 g++10 and were able to install those successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue installing openjdk13 :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-13-jre-headless : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.0) but it is not installable
```

I have to install gcc-10-base and libgcc-s1 from URLs in my Dockerfile before installing openjdk :

```
RUN curl -sLO http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/gcc-10-base_10-20200418-1_amd64.deb && dpkg -i gcc-10-base_10-20200418-1_amd64.deb
RUN curl -sLO http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libgcc-s1_10-20200418-1_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libgcc-s1_10-20200418-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the link in the page https://packages.debian.org/sid/arm64/gcc-9-base/download
to /etc/apt/sources.list
Second, run `apt --fix-broken install` without any package names
Reboot for good measure and re-try the installation of your package.